# Object has not method find?

Tags: jquery, object, find

```
var links = ""
$('#right').load('www.mywebsite.com/download', function(data) {
    data.find(".download-row a").each(function(){
        links += $(this).attr("href");
    });
});
```

When I run this code in console, it gives me Object has no method find. There' something I'm not getting...

I'm just trying to get that link

```
<div class="download-row">
    <a href="http://www.website.com">A website</a>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is `data`? If it's a string of HTML then it won't, unless you first wrap it in a jQuery object.

Comment: Perhaps `$(data).find()` will do the trick?

Comment: $(data).find() works, but now links is undefined.

Comment: In which context are you accessing links? What is the console.log output of `$(this).attr('href')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap data in a jQuery object in order to use the find() method. Also, if your links is undefined, you might want to first log your data to make sure your load() is working properly.

Comment: I think I finally understand why I'm having problems

Comment: I can't comment on your answer yet cause my reputation isn't high enough but the reason your first code doesn't load properly is cause it thinks it is a relative path because you didn't put `http://` to make it an absolute path and in your answer, having just download works because it is a relative path. Basically, `http://www.mywebsite.com/download` and `download` should both work.

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally understand what I did wrong.

The load function was accessing the wrong page, specifically

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/www.mywebsite.com/download
```

I was not supposed to put the full URL in, just "download"

The correct code:

```
$('#right').load('download', function(data) {
$(data).find(".download-row a").each(function(){
    links += $(this).attr("href");
});
```

});